# Unicode string to list

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-views

I have a list of dictionaries which I sent from my javascript file to my view.
Now, when i print the list, its type is shown as unicode. I want to get back the list I originally had. 
How can I do that?

My list :

```
[{"employee_id":13,"admin":false,"approver":false,"emp_code_or_email":"second@emp.com,120","manager":false,"emp_name":"second emp","department":"IT","position":"IT","new_emp":false,"manager_and_approver":false,"role_type":"employee","s_no":1},{"employee_id":144,"admin":false,"approver":false,"emp_code_or_email":"107anku@gmail.com,1","manager":true,"emp_name":"A1 A2","department":"IT","position":"Developer","new_emp":false,"manager_and_approver":false,"role_type":"manager","s_no":2}]
```

I just want to fetch the employee_ids from this.

I tried eval() , list(), encode('utf-8'). But to no avail.

Comment: Why is it a problem that the strings are now unicode values? They are *text* after all, and Python can handle the mix (provided you don't try to mix non-ASCII encoded data with Unicode).

Comment: You can *already* fetch the employee ids from that; `lst[0]['employee_id']` works wether the key is unicode or a byte string.

Comment: This entire list is unicode. I tried your code, but it gave me this error "string indices must be integers"

Comment: You mean you have *JSON* then?

Comment: employee_list = post_dict['emps']
print "emp list", employee_list, type(employee_list)
for emp in employee_list:
                print emp, type(emp)
                print "id", emp[0]['employee_id']
This is what I tried.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a string representation of a JSON. I can tell it by looking at `"admin":false` in order for you to get `employee_id`'s. You first need to convert every json representation you have in the list into dictionary.

```
>>> import json
>>> data_raw = '''[{"employee_id":13,"admin":false,"approver":false,"emp_code_or_email":"second@emp.com,120","manager":false,"emp_name":"second emp","department":"IT","position":"IT","new_emp":false,"manager_and_approver":false,"role_type":"employee","s_no":1},{"employee_id":144,"admin":false,"approver":false,"emp_code_or_email":"107anku@gmail.com,1","manager":true,"emp_name":"A1 A2","department":"IT","position":"Developer","new_emp":false,"manager_and_approver":false,"role_type":"manager","s_no":2}]'''
>>> data_json = json.loads(data_raw)
>>> [data['employee_id'] for data in data_json]
[13, 144]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you print any objects, python will display python representation of this object.

To display it the way you want, you should format your output.

But easiest way will be to convert it to json, since you recieve it from ajax.

```
import simplejson
simplejson.dumps(data)
```